# Print numbers as words?

Tags: php

Hi I was wondering how can I print out numbers in their word form ? When I did a Google search it showed other peoples script on how to print 234 as two hundred thirty four .

I need 234 as two three four.

Thank you guys!

Comment: check this http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Comment: an array, split the string, seems simple, try SOMETHING

Comment: I havent tried anything. Im completely new to php. Im getting the numbers passed in from an html form. So far i did $numbers = $_POST['thedata']

Comment: For all those who marked this as a duplicate, did you actually read the question? **I need 234 as two three four**, and the guy already knows about the scripts available to convert 234 into two hundred and thirty four.

Answer (score 2):

> I need 234 as two three four.

It would be as simple as creating an array of your number to word map, then taking your number and printing out the corresponding value:

```
<?php

   $num_word = array();
   $num_word[0] = 'zero';
   $num_word[1] = 'one';
   $num_word[2] = 'two'
   ...
   $num_word[9] = 'nine';

   $num = 234;

   foreach(str_split($num) as $w) {
       echo $num_word[$w];
   }
?>
```

Comment: since that the maximum number word that he need is nine, you can do this

Comment: +1, but don't forget a space when echoing, or you'll just get a strand of words.

Comment: Thank you Burhan! This is exactly what I was trying to do. Amazing how useful this site can be at an amazing speed too.

Comment: To add onto this, if I wanted to only print certain indexs, would that be possible with a foreach loop? For example if I wanted to print 2345

as three four (only the 2 middle numbers). Sorry my book that I'm currently using isn't very helpful.

Comment: Yes `foreach(str_split($num) as $index => $letter) {`